# Modifying an array during a foreach loop

Tags: php, object-oriented, array, php5

This question is always on my mind. I usually alter the array while looping through its keys, based on my gut feelings:

```
foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
  $array[$key] = perform_changes_on($array[$key]);
}
```

I'm aware of other methods, though. The array item can be passed by reference on the foreach call:

```
foreach ($array as &$item) {
  $item = perform_changes_on($item);  
}
```

Finally, the array can be modified directly during the loop:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = perform_changes_on($value);
}
```

What are the performance and security implications of each approach? Is there a recommended approach?

UPDATE: What I'm actually worried about is that the two last approaches modify the array while I'm looping it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works is helpful.

Comment: OP gave actual code and yet it's closed because the code is not part of a "concrete implementation"? honestly, what ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are worried about modifying the array while looping, don't because foreach copies the array. Try

```
$array = array('foo');
foreach ($array as $k => &$item) {
  $array[] = 'bar';
}
var_dump($array);
```

And see it terminates just fine. `foreach ($array as $k => &$v)` is a shorthand for `foreach (array_keys($array) as $k) $v = &$array[$k]` so while there still is a copy of the array (that's why I used `&$item` in my example so you can see, if you modify the array then it'll be modified in the reference!

```
$array = array('foo', 'bar');
foreach ($array as $k => $item) {
  echo "$item\n";
  if (!$k) {
    $array[1] = 'baz';
  }
}
$array = array('foo', 'bar');
foreach ($array as $k => &$item) {
  echo "$item\n";
  if (!$k) {
    $array[1] = 'baz';
  }
}
```

the first dump foo and bar, the second foo and baz.

Comment: "foreach ($array as $k => $v) is a shorthand for foreach (array_keys($array) as $k) $v = &$array[$k]"  On a very picky note, that's not a shorthand as much as a difference in calling a function and a language construct (though for practical reasons, I suppose it's a shorthand).  Also, it would be shorthand for a copy, not a reference.  (Also, PHP is copy-on-write, so you can typically ignore extra copies.)

Comment: Obviously that wanted to be `foreach ($array as $k => &$v)` edited and fixed.

Comment: Would like to point out that `if(!$k)` is TRUE for 0, otherwise this statement is always false. So essentially you are overwriting the second array element before ever seeing it.

Comment: I do that and by doing that, I am demonstrating that the first foreach works from a copy and the second doesn't.

Comment: @chx You might want to run your first snippet then.  $item is a copy of a value from $array.  `$array` is never copied (though all elements of `$array` will be copied if the foreach loop completes).  The first snippet will dump foo and baz just like the second one.

Comment: (Note that in your answer you've used dump to mean the outputting during the loop whereas I've used it to mean outputting the entire array after the loop.  Basically as in: http://paste.ee/p/hzqGz -- in short, I'm responding to your comment under the assumption that it's along the lines of what you posted in your answer: "foreach copies the array.")

Comment: Funny. I ran that snippet. I get foo, bar, foo, baz.

Comment: @chx, Isn't this just an implementation detail that might be changed in the future? The documentation (specification) doesn't state that `foreach` must perform as such.

Comment: @Corbin: I suppose @chx means that all `$item`s for every key-value-pair will be copied at instantiation, so that even though `$array[1]` will be altered to `baz` in the first loop, the second loop will still print `bar` as the value of `$item` even though in the actual array it will have already been updated.

Comment: Although the first snippet works on 5.x the way Chx describes (copying the array, iterating over the copy). As of PHP 7.0 the array is no longer copied. The snippet will instead iterate until the memory limit is reached. A good StackOverflow answer that goes into detail on this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-php-foreach-actually-work/14854568#14854568

Answer (score 10):

This sounds like a place for [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

```
$array = array_map('perform_changes_on', $array);
```

Comment: nice, but sometimes i won't change _every_ item in the array. I just tried to make the example simpler...

Comment: `perfom_changes_on` doesn't have to change every element. Note that there are other [array functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), some more powerful than others. [array_reduce](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) can help a lot, for example.

Comment: Doesn't this involve a function call for every element? May not be the best performance wise.

Comment: @Tom: I wouldn't say the overhead of function call is notable. Maintainability is way more important than very small performance gains (that I'm not even sure if they even do exist). But if you think that writing 100,000 lines program without functions is a best way of programming, by all means do it. Just don't be surprised when nobody wants to maintain the code, and you won't understand what you wrote a day later.

Answer (score 3):

When using `foreach($array as &$item)` never ever forget the `unset($item);` after the foreach or you will get into serious trouble trying to use `$item` later. It should be habitual to avoid this trap.

In general you should avoid `foreach ...&` and do `array_walk($array, function (&$item) {...` so that the reference is strictly confined inside the closure.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'm using array_keys to avoid the trap, but do I need to use it? I mean, `foreach ($array as $key => $item)` should let me change `$array[$key]` value, but who knows how php works internally... that's the question, actually.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really help you with the performance bit, only tell you to wrap them in `microtime()` tags and see which one performs better for you. Systems are slightly different. The one suggestion I can give you is to remove `array_keys()` from your code.

**!!UPDATE!!**

If you were following Corbin and my argument below, then I finally have an answer for you. I was getting for and foreach confused. For and while loops **do** call any functions passed in as arguments on every iteration, foreach **does not**. Which is why its better to call functions such as `strlen()` and `count()`, just to give a couple of examples, outside of a for or while loop. The overhead we were experiencing was not from foreach but from `array_keys()`. When `array_keys()` is called it must generate a new array, which is why it is almost twice as slow. So it is best to drop the `array_keys()` function all-together and just iterate over the array and retrieve the key value pair. Sorry for any confusion this may have caused.

Sources:

- http://www.phpbench.com/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430194/performance-of-for-vs-foreach-in-php
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740575/php5-does-the-copy-of-an-array-for-a-foreach-incur-overhead

**!!END OF UPDATE!!**

To the best of my knowledge there is no security risk with any of those implementations. You are iterating a construct that already exists. Any security issues would have happened before this point. Except of course if you are using user supplied data, such as GET and POST. These you should sanitize and validate before using, which is something you could do with one of those foreach loops. Or you could also check out [`filter_input_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php) and its cousins.

I know I personally would not use the second implementation due to the lack of legibility. At least with the first and third implementations you can visually see that a value is being changed. The second is not readily obvious. However, it is most likely the more efficient. I have used both the first and third myself, but more often use the third. Think it has to do with what mood I'm in. Hope this helps, I'm interested to hear what others might have to say :)

Comment: "Arguments given to foreach are declared on each iteration, so you are technically calling array_keys() every time foreach is looped."  Nope, it will only call array_keys once in this context.  (Perhaps before PHP5 it had this behavior, but I do not think so as this would very easily end up in infinite loops.)

Comment: @Corbin: **Nope**, still an issue. Don't believe me, run some tests on it and you'll see for yourself. PHP creates an iterator object for the first parameter each time it loops so that it can perform `each()` on each iteration of it. It is recreated, but the pointer stays the same. That's why if you changed the value of the array by reference it would be immediately available upon the next iteration :)

Comment: Can you provide an example?  Just tried to get it to call array_keys (well, `f`) twice, and could never get it to.

Comment: Potentially relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043569/php-foreach-function-performance

Comment: @Corbin: I'm honestly not sure then. I've seen someone else claiming the exact opposite, and my speed tests seem to prove it. The foreach with the "recreated" array always seems to take longer. Ran a test of over a hundred iterations and all seem conclusive that something extra is being performed in the background. I'm still looking around for that post, hopefully I can find it. I need to start keeping a repository of these posts...

Comment: It's easy to prove that the function is not called over and over again.  Just use `foreach(f($arr) as $v) { }` with an `echo` in `f`.  However, if there is actually a performance difference, no idea what that is from.

Comment: Did some very rough testing a minute ago, and the results are quite odd.  `foreach(f($x) ...)` is significantly faster for small arrays, and `$fx =  f($x); foreach ($fx ...)` is faster for large arrays.  There must be some very odd low level stuff going on >.<.

Comment: I was not able to find that post, but as you have seen with your own speed tests "something" is going on. So the while my reasoning behind it is wrong, its still better to separate the creation of the array from the loop. Or at the very least it won't hurt anything.

Comment: You're neglecting the case where it's faster to inline the function :)

Comment: @Corbin: Alright, finally figured it out. See update above...

Comment: "The overhead we are experiencing is not from foreach but from array_keys() which requires some setup time that drastically decreases its performance." does not make sense (nor is it drastic), but definitely better than before the edit :).  (Sorry for being 'that guy', just there's a lot of misinformation about a few edges of PHP, and it makes me sad :p.)  Also, you should edit out the `Arguments given to foreach...` part :).

Comment: Drastic was perhaps misleading, I meant so relatively speaking. I don't see how that didn't make sense, but I edited it to, hopefully, clarify. Continue being that guy. I'd rather someone caught me now, rather than years down the line after having given many people the wrong information.

Comment: I suppose reading back on it now that I read it with the wrong context in mind.  I think it's a lot clearer now, but I think it was me over thinking things and misunderstanding it before.  Though the paragraph still sounds like it's comparing for and foreach's performances instead of `foreach (array_keys($arr) ... )` compared to `$keys = array_keys($arr); foreach ($keys)` compared to `foreach ($array as ...)`.)

Comment: The answer might also be a bit misleading to people who don't read the comments since `foreach (f() ...)` compared to `$vals = f(); foreach ($vals ... )` is essentially the same performance whereas `foreach (array_keys($array) ...)` and `foreach ($array as $k => $v)` will have different performances (not because of a function call, but because of what the function is doing -- basically recreating a language construct in a hacky way.  As you said, if you do the array_keys approach, the keys have to all be copied.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with your second approach:

```
foreach ($array as &$item) {
  $item = perform_changes_on($item);  
}
```

Or even better:

```
function perform_changes_on(&$item) {
// ...
}

foreach ($array as &$item) {
  perform_changes_on($item);  
}
// ...
```

Working on each item (by reference) seems the safest one, since you're not accessing the array's structure, but its single elements instead (which, I take, is what you want to do).